# Colspan not getting applied correctly

Tags: html, css, angular

I have generated a dynamic table in angular 7. I am trying to do a colspan which is creating additional elements at the end. Not sure why? Also what I need is that the colspan needs to be dynamic. for e.g, the columns could be any number. Depending on the column number the colspan should apply. If you see here the columns are based on the number of records

HTML:

```
<div *ngIf="LegalFundClasses && LegalFundClasses.LegalFundClassDetailsViewModel && ColumnNames">


  <table class="fundClassesTable table-striped">
    <tr *ngFor="let c of ColumnNames">
      <th class="tableItem bold">{{ c }}</th>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let f of LegalFundClasses.LegalFundClassDetailsViewModel">
        <td class="tableItem" *ngIf="c == ColumnNames[0]">{{f.Description}}</td>
        <td class="tableItem" *ngIf="c == ColumnNames[1]">{{f.AuditSummary}}</td>
        <td class="tableItem" *ngIf="c == ColumnNames[2]">{{f.Id}}</td>
        <td class="tableItem" *ngIf="c == ColumnNames[3]">COMMERCIAL TERMS</td>
        <td class="tableItem" *ngIf="c == ColumnNames[4]">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn" style="float: left;" (click)="buttonClicked(f.Id)">Review Terms</button>
        </td>
        <td [colSpan]="8" class="tableItem" *ngIf="c == ColumnNames[5]"></td>
        <td *ngIf="!EditMode[f.Id] && c == ColumnNames[6]" class="tableItem"> {{f.PrimaryCurrencyName}}</td>
        <td *ngIf="EditMode[f.Id]  && c == ColumnNames[6]" class="tableItem">
          <kendo-dropdownlist style="width:100%" [(ngModel)]="f.CurrencyId" [defaultItem]="defaultItem" class="form-control  form-control-sm" [data]="LegalFundClasses.Currencies" [filterable]="false" textField="Name" [valuePrimitive]="true" valueField="Id">
          </kendo-dropdownlist>
        </td>

      </ng-container>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

I am sharing the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s527kfvn/).

Comment: The structure of the `<table>` looks wrong to me. Looks like you are repeating `[colSpan]` many times on a single row.

Answer (score 0):

Try using  `[attr.colspan]`

Eg:

```
[attr.colspan]="8"
```

Comment: Did you try in the fiddle i gave you as it doesnt work for me in the actual code

Answer (score 0):

Use `colspan` as 1, looks like you are trying to assign one column for each record.

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qf4dy20c/)

Comment: Can't see extra elements in the end, what the actual issue?\

Comment: Put 7 or 8 for colspan in the fiddle and you will see it

Comment: I think the issue is the for loop

Answer (score 0):

You need to include index in your *ngIf and *ngFor. You are iterating over the td 7 times and colspan=8 on each of them. This way you just add the td on the first iteration.

```
    <table class="fundClassesTable table-striped" border="1">
      <tr *ngFor="let c of ColumnNames; let i = index">
        <th class="tableItem bold">{{ c }}</th>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let f of data">
          <td class="tableItem" *ngIf="c == ColumnNames[0]">{{f.Description}}</td>
          <td class="tableItem" *ngIf="c == ColumnNames[1]">{{f.AuditSummary}}</td>
          <td class="tableItem" *ngIf="c == ColumnNames[2]">{{f.Id}}</td>
           <td class="tableItem" *ngIf="c == ColumnNames[3]">COMMERCIAL TERMS</td>
          <td class="tableItem" *ngIf="c == ColumnNames[4]">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn" style="float: left;"
                  (click)="buttonClicked(f.Id)">Review Terms</button>
          </td>
          <td [colSpan]="8" class="tableItem" *ngIf="c == ColumnNames[5] && i == 0"></td>
          <td  *ngIf="c == ColumnNames[6]" class="tableItem"> {{f.PrimaryCurrencyName}}</td>

        </ng-container>
      </tr>
      </table>
```